# Any pattern of same length that isn't the pattern desired

Tags: r, regex

Using Adobe Acrobat Pro to convert a pdf table to excel, which was then read into R, I am fixing all elements of a column (say ID) to match what was originally in the pdf, because the conversion created some problems. (i.e. 5 became S, 8 became B or S, 0 O and D were interchanged, 6 became 0, I became 1, spaces were added, etc) I have used regex to fix all elements thus far, and some that can't be fixed except manually, and recreated the excel sheet with the corrections. This is a monthly project and future errors might occur. I want to create a regular expression to find anything that still does not match the desired pattern and append a marker (i.e. %, or ?, or !)

The desired pattern follows an XYY pattern, where X is [A-T] and Y is [0-2] and [0-9] respectively. The lowest being A01, highest being T25. I want to find anything that is outside this "range" or incorrect still and add the marker. Thus far I have attempted the following. I cannot provide the data for sake of confidentiality.

Here is a made-up example that should get the point across.

```
mydf <- data.frame(ID = c("A01", "J31", "K24", "L12", "T26", "810"))
mydf$ID <- gsub("(^[^A-T][02][0-9])", "\\1!", mydf$ID)
```

but this yields nothing.
I also tried to use this:

```
!grepl("^[A-T][0-2][0-9]$", mydf$ID)
```

Then I could mark all ID's that are incorrect. It catches that J31 and 810 are incorrect but misses T26 as an incorrect ID.

You may assume that all ID's will be the same length, 3 characters. 
R code is required.

Comment: Why would T26 be incorrect? X=T, [A-T]/Y=2,[0-2] /Y=6, [0-9]

Comment: I think you're looking for something like this? `!grepl("[A-S][0-2][0-9]|T[0-1][0-9]|T[2][0-5]",mydf$ID)`

Comment: Try `grep("^[A-T](?:[01][0-9]|2[0-5])$", mydf$ID, invert=TRUE, value=TRUE)`

Comment: @Chabo The range desired stops at T25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think just naively breaking it into 3 possible cases will work. Something like:

```
mydf <- data.frame(ID = c("A01", "J31", "K24", "L12", "T26", "810"))
mydf$ID <- gsub("((?:[^A-T].{2})|(?:[A-T][3-9].)|(?:[A-T]2[6-9]))", "\\1!", mydf$ID)
```

Note that this does assume that there are exactly 3 digits.

Comment: I feel like these cases aren't quite adequate, but they might work for now. I'm wondering why you used .{2} instead of... something else?

Comment: If the first character isn't between A and T, then it doesn't matter what follows it. So the first part should catch anything that doesn't start correctly.

The second case should get something that starts with a correct character, but is 30 or more.

The third case should get things that start with a correct character, but between 26 and 29.

Comment: How would you change this to make sure that letters aren't found in the second or third position, which is also possible. Or numbers in the first position. Sorry, I just want this to be as thorough as possible

Comment: Just add letters to the number ranges.

Comment: mydf <- data.frame(ID = c("A01", "J31", "K24", "L12", "T26", "810", "123", "BA2", "B2a"))

Comment: mydf$ID <- gsub("((?:[^A-T].{2})|(?:[A-T][3-9A-z].)|(?:[A-T]2[6-9A-z]))", "\\1!", mydf$ID)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with negative lookarounds, which requires `perl = TRUE` in `gsub`. Basically I change your pattern to be the positive match (need start, then A-T, then 0-1 and 0-9, or 2 and 0-5, then end character) and include `?!` to indicate don't look for this. Note that you left out a hyphen above . However, negative regex is not always very clear and it may be easier to understand if you simply use `stringr::str_detect` or `grepl` with positive matching and then negate the resulting logical vector to use as an indicator column.

```r
mydf <- data.frame(ID = c("A01", "J31", "K24", "L12", "T26", "810", "A012", "AA12"))
mydf$ID <- gsub("(^(?!^([A-T][0-1][0-9]|[A-T]2[0-5])$).*)", "\\1!", mydf$ID, perl = TRUE)
mydf$ID
#> [1] "A01"   "J31!"  "K24"   "L12"   "T26!"  "810!"  "A012!" "AA12!"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I'm not certain why you added ID's that are longer than the assumption of 3 characters. This might work if that addition wasn't there.

Comment: It should still work, I didn't see that was safe to assume. You can see the original strings are still marked correctly.